# Would be him vs will be him

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

Suppose a telephone is ringing and I think that this call is from a specific person, then what will I say?

> That would be him.
> That wil be him.

Comment: Both OK. No difference. Just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Or "That's him"